# can I use Google AMP with Ghost cms + Next.Js project?

Tags: next.js, amp-html, ghost-blog

I'm trying to implement AMP in my blog posts which is a part of my Next.js project. My blog posts are coming from Ghost CMS, So my question here is can I use AMP with my blog posts ? And if I can, where should I enable AMP ? should I implement it in the Next.js project ? Or Should I enable it in the Ghost CMS and it will automatically send an AMP ready version to the project using the fetch method ?

Answer (score 0):

Ghost comes with a built-in integration for Google AMP which transforms all of the content on your site into an AMP version.

Read more about it here - https://ghost.org/integrations/google-amp/

Comment: so I will just enable Google AMP Integration in the Ghost and when my Projects renders the content it will be already an AMP version ?

Comment: yes, and it's already enabled. you can check the amp link by adding /amp in the link. Check here: normal link - https://lyra.ghost.io/welcome/ and amp-link -https://lyra.ghost.io/welcome/amp/

Comment: Alright, Thanks a lot for your help, I was stuck in this problem forever

Comment: btw you said its already enabled in the Ghost cms and there are 2 versions, what should I do if i wanna send only the AMP version to my Next.js project ? yes if i add /amp to the Ghost link I can see the AMP version, but how do I fetch that version from my project ?